# A question on semi-martingale and its variations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning, martingales

> With probability one, paths of semimartingales have unbounded variation.

What I know is that a martingale is also a semi-martingale, for example, Brownian motion. Hence, Brownian is an example of semi-martingale with unbounded variation. Is the above statement generally ture? If so, how to show it? Otherwise, what is a counter example? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above statement is not true. Semimartingales are a quite general class of processes containing processes of both bounded and unbounded variation. For example a constant process $(X_t) \equiv 0 $ is a semimartingale.

Comment: Thank you! Is there other less trivial counter examples, please?

Comment: Poisson process is a semimartingale. Generally, a semimartingale can be represented as a sum of a local martingale and a finite-variation process. This the Bichteler-Dellacharie theorem: http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/the-bichteler-dellacherie-theorem/